# pip install opencv-python causing "No usable temporary directory found"

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I've made a program in Python 3.9... on Windows, I'm now trying to make this run on my Raspberry Pi 4. The code imports PIL and cv2 so I pip installed both. Turns out the Raspberry Pi had Python 2.x.x so I followed a tutorial for installing Python 3.10 which I have now done, although I don't think it is in the correct place or setup properly.

Therefore when I try `pip3 install opencv-python` it shows an error of:

```
No usable temporary directory found in ...
```

I feel like it's something to do with PATH, root, permissions or something like that but I have no idea what to try or where to start.

I've already in the past installed Python 3.7.x which comes up when I do `python3 -V` so it's not detecting 3.10.x as the newest version.

Comment: Show us the output of `$ df -k`, and of `$ env | sort | grep -i 'tmp|temp'`. Is it possible that disk quota is enabled? Are you _sure_ the desired temp dir has wide-open "a+rwx" permission so any user may write to it? Are you able to create a 1 MiB file in /tmp using `cp` ? Does a reboot change the symptom? Examining the output of `$ mount` will sometimes reveal a FS is readonly when you didn't expect that.

Comment: @J_H will do, it's now going back to the login screen after entering password. Apparantly it's a known issue so I've got to try and fix that first now.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.10?

Comment: @Chris Following a tutorial, these were the commands I ran: wget <url> /// tar -zxvf Python-<version>.tgz /// tar -zxvf <filename> /// cd Python-<version> /// ./configure --enable-optimizations /// sudo make altinstall Note: I was in a folder within the documents folder which is where it was downloaded to, extracted, etc. Also, /// seperates the commands